# Cannot log into my RADIUS protected wireless connection. Here's the LOG contents

Tags: freeradius

As soon as someone tries to connect to my network, this appears in the log:

```
Tue May  3 15:58:40 2011 : Error: TLS Alert read:fatal:unknown CA 
Tue May  3 15:58:40 2011 : Error:     TLS_accept:failed in SSLv3 read client certificate A 
Tue May  3 15:58:40 2011 : Error: rlm_eap: SSL error error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
Tue May  3 15:58:40 2011 : Error: rlm_eap_tls: SSL_read failed inside of TLS (-1), TLS session fails.
Tue May  3 15:58:40 2011 : Auth: Login incorrect: [steve/<no User-Password attribute>] (from client test port 18 cli 0ceee6b55136)
```

After Googling a bit this seems to be a problem with certificates on the client side, correct?

I'm using FreeRadius.NET hosted on Windows 7 and I'm trying to connect to the wireless network via a Windows 7 client.

After running the application in debug mode and trying again, I get this error. Pardon the screenshot, I cannot copy text in Windows command line.

[image]

Am I correct in this assumption that the certificate is the cause of the error? I'm 100% sure that there is a user named `steve`:

```
//In users.conf
steve User-Password == "testing"
```

Comment: "Pardon the screenshot, I cannot copy text in Windows command line." I do quite a bit of work with FreeRADIUS. You should be running this on a Unix or Linux box. It's complicated enough to debug *with* the help of the whole FreeRADIUS community, you don't also need to run it on a weird operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server is failing on the client certificate portion of authentication.  [Here's a how-to](https://web.archive.org/web/20110905011026/http://freeradius.org/doc/EAPTLS.pdf) from FreeRADIUS on how to set up EAP-TLS, or alternatively you can set it to not require a client cert by setting it for a different EAP mechanism in `eap.conf`.

Comment: Thank you! :) This seems to be what will solve my issue.

Comment: The link is broken. This is exactly the reason people should not post link only answers. Could expand your answer to include the information from the link?